# jquery element properties is not loading in rjs file elements?

Tags: jquery, rjs, rails-3.1

I am using rails3 , In my application auto complete-functionality is there. When users/new template auto-complete functionality working. users/new is a partial file also. If I want to call as a ajax request that file , auto-complete field not working.

From my knowledge jquery properties not applying to rjs or partial file elements .

Thanks in Advance,
Prasad.